# How to implement z buffering algorithm

Tags: 3d, zbuffer

For a project I want to implement  Z-buffer in 3d model. I know the algorithm and i need how to implement this.

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: how to implement z buffering algorithm in python or any other language

Comment: You just need to think about it: if a new pixel / fragment is closer to the view: use the colour, and set (x,y) depth. You don't give any details about the [implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-buffering). It's a lazy question.

Comment: @user2177232 this is very high level question, to the point that it is impossible to answer it. If you have an algorithm try to break it down into steps.